Chromatic note and mode degrees
I’m into generative music (and know that classical music specialists are skeptical about it).
But it’s a non-profit project, just self-development and research.
Also sorry for the inaccuracies in terminology.
Within the project there is a midi analysis.
Compilation of hash-tables pitch1 → pitch2 or even
(pitch1, pitch2)  → pitch3.
But it is much more interesting to study modes,
and analyze how and with what probability one degree passes into another.
And here the question arises with chromatic notes.
If chromatic note is between degrees d1 and d2,
is it raised d1 or lowered  d2?
I understand that the answer depends on the context.
Let’s limit to the major and minor and will not investigate harmony.
Updated
Thank you very much for your answers, I have understood the role of harmony and will continue to reflect.
But another difficulty has arisen.
There is a rule that an ascending passage of chromatic scale is spelled with sharps and a descending - with flats.
So even if we read human-readable format, how can we tell
in which case the composer used raised/lowered degrees, and in which - this rule?

I’d say what you really want to ask is “raised” or “lowered” because “augmented” and “diminished” are not always the best words for what you’re asking about. The problem is, as you already know, we can’t answer this question, because it depends on context. Maybe you want to ask how to tell if it’s raised or lowered?

@ToddWilcox  thank you, fix something!

For practical purposes, why does it matter given they have the same pitch (with the right caveats about tuning etc)?

@HNHN In practice, as the OP tries to explain, there is a machine which maps (translates) notes between tables, and depending on which slot a note is placed in, the machine will produce a different mapping for the note. The note will end up in a different target slot and it will have a different target pitch.

@piiperiReinstateMonica I work in generative AI, I know what OP is trying to do. I understand why OP’s question is relevant from a music analysis perspective, I don’t understand why it is relevant from a midi generation perspective, which is what I think OP is trying to do. So I’m asking in order to clarify the problem formulation.

Note names and accidentals are a part of a language, a part of a culture where musicians think of harmonic contexts as having seven possible different pitches per octave at any one time. Notes have names in order to facilitate human communication and reasoning. Note spellings are cultural conventions and they come from a subjective perspective of a composer or musician.
Your question "should this be a raised degree 1 or a lowered degree 2" is a way of asking how to do enharmonic spelling. The fact that you use numbers or array indices instead of letter names does not change anything. Enharmonic spellings depend on how you want to look at the harmonic context. You say let's not investigate harmony. That's not possible. Whenever different pitched notes are heard, even sequentially and not sounding at the same time, they inevitably form a harmonic context in the listener's mind. The question "should this be a raised degree 1 or a lowered degree 2" is a question about harmony, that is, what is the set of seven possible notes. If I want to have degree 2 available as-is in my note palette (harmonic context) at that moment, then I'll make it a raised degree 1. If I want to have degree 1 available as-is in my note palette (harmonic context) at that moment, then I'll make it a lowered degree 2.
Generally, it's not possible to algorithmically decide a "correct" note name spelling without defining a perspective, a harmonic context.
Counter-example: you start from C major scale and you have MIDI notes 60 and 61. Note 60 could be, say, B#2 or Dbb3 (D double-flat), but since 60 is found in the scale with the name C3, we'll assume that's its "correct" spelling is probably C. But 61 is not in the scale with any name, so 61 must be chromatic. Our question is: does it better serve our purposes of communication and reasoning to call note 61 C# or Db? Since we already know it is "chromatic", we have to assume that some kind of a harmonic alteration is probably going on.
In what sort of situations starting from a C major context could I have a C# or Db? If I'm doing a secondary dominant sort of trick, like with chords C - A7 - D7 - G7 - C, during the A7 chord C is sharp and MIDI note 61 could be in that chord. But I could also do something like a tritone substitution, C - A7 - D7 - Db7 - C. The Db7 chord is used as a substitute for G7, and during that chord, note 61 would be Db. If you want to have the notes 60 and 61 at the same time, we could do C - A7 - D7 - Dbmaj7 - Cmaj7.
Another example. You have MIDI note numbers: 60, 63, 66, 69. A musician will immediately hear a Cdim7 chord. The theoretically correct names for the pitches are: 60:C, 63:Eb, 66:Gb, 69:Bbb. But if these pitches are played over the D7 chord in the chord progression above, you notice it's a modified D7 chord, and you could also legitimately see it as being rooted on F# which is the leading tone for G, so then the pitches would be named 66:F#, 69:A, 60:C, 63:Eb. Why, what sense does this naming make? The notes are named like that to satisfy a cultural convention (or obsession) where chords are thought of as being constructed as a stack of thirds. That means taking every other slot in the scale. A full seven-note chord would have scale degrees 1-3-5-7-9-11-13, or if you think "modulo 7" and zero-based indexing, it's 0-2-4-6-1-3-5. A four-note C-something chord must have: C-something, E-something, G-something, and B-something. And that's why get 60:C, 63:Eb, 66:Gb, 69:Bbb.
Ask yourself: for what purpose do you need to decide if a MIDI note number should mapped to a raised degree 1 or a lowered degree 2? What practical operation goes wrong if you make the wrong decision?

Thank you very much!
Well, I guessed that had touched on a difficult subject, but did not expect that much.
Let’s focus on context. Now I’m listening to Bach Suites for Solo Cello BWV 1007-1012
These are monophony works with a little chromaticism.
I try to construct a graph of possible transitions between the degrees.
And it would be important and interesting to understand to what degree chromatic notes are "tend"

@lesobrod If your source material is something like Bach, then I'd recommend using actual notation that has enharmonic spellings worked out, and not MIDI where the spellings have been removed. What language and library are you using? The music21 package for Python has hundreds of Bach pieces included as MusicXML files, and I suppose the files are available from other sources as well. BWV 1007 seems to be available in Abc notation as well.

@lesobrod BWV 1007 in Abc format https://gitlab.com/chrisspen/abc-music/-/blob/master/guitar/bach-cello-suite-prelude-guitar.abc?ref_type=heads

Converting my comments to an answer.
My background in generative AI is stronger than my background in music, so I'll answer from that perspective (hoping I won't get downvoted for this): given the answer already provided, I think it would be better to revisit your problem formulation and modeling approach.
If the problem formulation is, given a large corpus of midi-based simple melodies labeled with their tonal center, I want to generate melodies sampled from the distribution of the data, then a simple n-gram based approach is sufficient and the specific notation a human would use for a given pitch doesn't matter much. You can simply label 12 semitones and learn the probability of transitions to each from given n-grams as context. Translating the generated pitches back to scale degrees is more of an exercise in interpretation.
If your intent is to model music as a language in its complexity, we already have years of NLP experience telling us that n-grams are of limited utility. In this case I would look into transformers which are specifically designed to capture contextual relationships between language elements. In this case you will need a large corpus of music scores in a machine-readable format, and you will need to deal with tokenizing and representing the data in a meaningful way, but given the fact we have music notation software which has some data representation format, I assume it's a solved problem.
If you want to take an approach between these two, assuming that for each chromatic note you have it's associated human-notated label, you can model the probability of it being a raised d1 or a lowered d2 given the context.
Enjoy the project it sounds like a lot of fun :)

Looking at a lot of questions on this forum, I can't help thinking, these AI hobbyists aren't seeing the forest for the trees. Are they not considering the possibility of there being structural macro blocks contained in the note sequences? Musical notes are not independent atoms, they outline shapes harmonically and rhythmically. Particularly in something like Bach, there's no statistical random fluff, it's quite carefully crafted. If it was graphical images, I suppose that even a beginner hobbyist would pose questions like "what does this picture depict" or "what objects are there". :)

@piiperiReinstateMonica Well, it’s non obvious and quite profound - as a late beginner in music, it was a revelation for me and I am still struggling to fully comprehend its implications :) In OP’s defense I will say that the techniques they are using are language modeling techniques, so they have the right idea, it’s just that the specific method is not powerful enough to capture the language of music which is why I suggested a more powerful one.


"...and will not investigate harmony"

You really can't answer without the harmonic context. Ex. pitch 1 is G, pitch 2 is A, and you want the chromatic pitch between them, which could be either G sharp or A flat.
If the key were C and the chord at that chromatic pitch were, for example, an Fm chord, the chromatic pitch would be A flat.
On the other hand, assuming the same key of C, but the chord were E7, the chromatic pitch would be G sharp.
Many, many other examples could be given, but the point is there is no absolute way to determine such chromatic pitches. The technical term is enharmonic spelling. Ex. A flat and G sharp are alternative enharmonic spellings.
You would need to provide more info about your project to get a more detailed explanation. If your project does not deal with staff notation, you might not need to worry about enharmonic spellings. In terms of things like MIDI or piano key numbers, or notation like guitar tablature, there is no enharmonic spelling distinctions. It is really a matter of reading major/minor key music from staff notation.
